# Mass Delete and other mass actions on Inventory grid throwing errors

Tags: massaction

We added some extra functionality to an Product inventory grid and now the default actions that were previously there all fail with this error below. Note products are selected with a check in the checkbox. So not sure why it says that "something needs to be selected" Any ideas what we forgot to do?

[image]

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An item needs to be selected. Select and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An item needs to be selected. Select and try again.
<pre>#1 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#2 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#3 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#4 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassStatus/Interceptor.php:26]
#5 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#7 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassStatus\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
```

Comment: Please make sure you run ```php bin/magento setup:di:compile``` also provide more information on the module you are using to try to reproduce. It appears that the selected product ids never arrived in the post controller.

Comment: Thanks. Compile has been done. Its this extension here but we added some extra functionality. Those parts work ok but the default actions have the error now.  https://www.iksanika.com/products/stock-inventory-manager-magento-2.html